Inverting Point Doubling in ECC?
There are (at least) two well-known operations in Elliptic-Curve Cryptography, namely

Point Addition: One maps $(P, Q)\mapsto P + Q$, and
Point Doubling: One maps $P\mapsto P + P = 2P$.

I'm interested in whether one can "undo" this second operation, meaning that given some $Q = 2P$, can one efficiently recover $P$?

Are you asking if, given an elliptic curve point $P = 2Q$, there is an efficient way to recover $Q$ from $P$?

Yes I am looking for it

You're interested in is called "point halving". We have previous questions+answers on this topic. I've closed your question as a duplicate and linked to a particular one that should help. Note that the "even order" assumption appears to be the only hard case. If the order $|G|$ is odd, one can just compute $2^{-1}\bmod |G|$, and the multiply by this efficiently using standard techniques, e.g. writing it in binary to decompose it as a sequence of doublings and additions, in an additive variant of exponentiation by squaring.

If the linked question doesn't answer your question/you have further questions, feel free to ask a new question regarding whatever you're confused about.

Yes, even is hard, odd is easy Point halving formula for Koblitz curve over prime field
